# How can I pass an element of a vector as argument for `.push()` into the same vector without introduction of a temporary variable?

Tags: rust

This example fails:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<i8> = vec![1, 2];
    v.push(v[0])
}
```

error message:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `v` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
 --> src/main.rs:3:12
  |
3 |     v.push(v[0])
  |     -      ^   - mutable borrow ends here
  |     |      |
  |     |      immutable borrow occurs here
  |     mutable borrow occurs here
```

I knew how to fix this:

```
let mut v: Vec<i8> = vec![1, 2];
let take = v[0];
v.push(take);
```

How can I pass an element of a vector as argument for `.push()` into the same vector without introduction of a temporary variable?

Comment: You cannot until non-lexical lifetimes are implemented.